# Clever way to wakeup Android background service on shake

Tags: android, service, accelerometer, battery, background-service

I want my Android background to go into *sleep* mode - **but then** *wake up when the user starts moving*.
However, if I use the accelerometer in [NORMAL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL) mode (the lowest sample rate ~ 5Hz) I fear it would still consume too much power.
The best way to do it so far is on [USER_PRESENT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_USER_PRESENT) - screen on and unlocked.

Not even [screen on(possibly with keyguard present)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SCREEN_ON) works, because, as many of you may know, there are plenty of bad apps out there that will hold a wakelock and start the screen from time to time.

I am contemplating having the user push the volume up/down buttons..

Is there any better solution to this?

Comment: You could trigger a ~1 second sensors check periodically via AlarmManager but that risks missing the event.

Comment: It's a good idea. But as you said, if it misses the event, then it would be 2-3 seconds before my service wakes up. After wake up, it has to do something fast, so any delay will cost me...

Answer (score 0):

don't know if you're still looking for a way to do this, but i discovered (by accident) that you can start a shakeListener, and your app will get the events, even when in the background.

(and by "by accident", i mean that i did not want my app playing the sound that it is supposed to play when the app is in the background, but even when had another app in the background, and then even put the phone to sleep, when i would walk with the phone in my pocket, it was enough shaking to cause the app to perform the operation in the background.)

```
    /**
     * load and set up the listener for shake detection
     */
    private void loadShaker() {
        mShaker = new ShakeListener(this);
        mShaker.setOnShakeListener(new ShakeListener.OnShakeListener () {
            public void onShake() { 
                if (!mActivityPaused)
                    performMyOperationCausedByShake();
                }
        });
    }
```

you could probably thus set this up so that `performMyOperationCausedByShake()` performs an intent that causes your desired Activity to happen.

(it might be the case that this is not quite sensitive enough for what you're looking for …)

Comment: do you set up a receiver in your manifest file?  if so, care 2 share?  tks!

Comment: @john.k.doe Can you give a link to ShakeListener source code or documentation?